# ChaiJS: Cannot cause test to fail

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to get my second spec to fail but it won't. I am returning a `statusCode 203` from my server, and the test receives it as `203`, but for some reason the `expect` block still does not throw an error. What is going on here?

**spec.js**

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var request = require('request');
var localServerUri = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/';

describe('server http routing', function(done){
  it('should receive a status code 200 after GET request', function() {
    request(localServerUri + 'pull', function (error, response, body) {
      expect(response.statusCode).to.be.at(200);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should receive a status code 201 after POST request', function() {
    request.post({url:localServerUri + 'push', form: {key:'value'}}, function(err, response, body) { 
      //why wont this fail?
      console.log(response.statusCode === 201);
      expect(response.statusCode === 201).to.be.true;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

**app.js**
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

```
app.get('/pull', function (req, res) {
  res.send('works');
});

app.post('/push', function(req, res) {
  res.status(203);
  res.send('works');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at port', host, port);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `done` into the `it` blocks, not `describe`.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var request = require('request');
var localServerUri = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/';

describe('server http routing', function(){
  it('should receive a status code 200 after GET request', function(done) {
    request(localServerUri + 'pull', function (error, response, body) {
      expect(response.statusCode).to.be.at(200);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should receive a status code 201 after POST request', function(done) {
    request.post({url:localServerUri + 'push', form: {key:'value'}}, function(err, response, body) { 
      expect(true).to.be.true;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. The callbacks you pass to both of your `it` calls should be `function (done) {...` instead of `function () {...`. Right now, Mocha thinks these tests are synchronous, so it does not wait for them to complete.

The callback you pass to `describe` takes a `done` parameter but this is useless.